# vue3 youtube-player video playback id error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

The youtube-player icon appears on the screen, but the video does not play and an error with the video playback ID is displayed

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <YouTube url="https://youtu.be/GQmO52f26Ws" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import YouTube from 'vue3-youtube'
</script>
```

Comment: vue-youtube accepts a src attribute, not a url.

Answer (score 0):

*vue3-youtube use src as source url and play video on ready state from video id.*

You can replace your code with this format and get video in frame.

```html
<template>
  <YouTube 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw" 
    @ready="onReady"
    ref="youtube"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import YouTube from 'vue3-youtube'

export default defineComponent({
  components: { YouTube },
  methods: {
    onReady() {
      this.$refs.youtube.playVideo()
    },
  },
})
</script>
```